# Cropping image - Image.crop function not working

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have following line of code for image cropping

```
im = Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')

outfile = "path/to/dest_img.jpg"
im.copy()

im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))
im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```

But it doesn't seems cropping image. I have bigger image size e.g. 2048 x 1536 px.

[edited]

Here's solution too, I could not answer this question myself so adding answer here.

Actually crop return image with new handler, I realized where I make mistake. I should have assign crop in new handler, as bellow

```
crop_img = im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))
```

Complete code below:

```
im = Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')

outfile = "path/to/dest_img.jpg"
im.copy()

crop_img = im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))
crop_img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
crop_img.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```

Notice, after crop line, there is crop_img handler being used.

Comment: what is "size" ? I don't see you defining the size attribute (tuple) in your code. if you are cropping and resizing, you will need the size attribute assigned too.

Comment: Actually crop return image with new handler, I realized where I make mistake. I should have assign crop in new handler, as bellow

    crop_img = im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))

Dam... I can not post answer for my question before 8 hrs. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have forgotten to assign the return values in some statements.

```
im = Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')

outfile = "path/to/dest_img.jpg"

im = im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))
im = im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```

Comment: Why do you keep im.copy() and size that is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly want to do this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('sth.jpg')

outfile = "sth2.jpg"
region=im.crop((0, 0, 500, 500))
#Do some operations here if you want but on region not on im!
region.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```