# How to chop up an image and display individual squares

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop

I have an image that is 3000 by 3000, I am just wondering how do I chop up an image into 200x200. Currently I have a code that does it, but it doesnt return me the images.

```
pil_image = Image.open(big_image_path)#convert('RGB') #No need to RGB because originally RGB\

max_x, max_y = pil_image.size

max_col = math.floor(max_x / 200)
max_row = math.floor(max_y / 200)

defect_list = [(pil_image.crop((200*c, 200*r, 200*(c + 1), 200*(r + 1)))),
        "start_y": 200*r,
        "end_y":200*(r+1),
        "start_x": 200*c,
        "end_x":200*(c+1)]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Check this out, it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735554/cropping-image-image-crop-function-not-working/7735724

Comment: What even is the `defect_list`? It doesn't look like valid python to me but rather like a mix between a dictionary and a list. How is it supposed to return you the images, there isn't even any operation performed.

Comment: @sunnytown i was just passed an image of 3000 x 3000. In it theres a couple of defects like broken wires, wires that have been rusted. I created a json file and i've trained my model but i'm not sure how to proceed from there